# Windows machine not routing traffic to correct NIC

Tags: windows, routing

I have a windows laptop with two NICs. One is a wireless interface (used for general internet usage), the other is cellular modem using a SIM which makes it a part of private network (IP 10.100.100.12)

When both these interfaces are enabled, my routing table looks like

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.104     35
     10.100.100.8  255.255.255.248         On-link     10.100.100.12    257
    10.100.100.12  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.100.100.12    257
    10.100.100.15  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.100.100.12    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.88.114    281
```

The problem is, when I try to ping some device on the cellular network e.g) 10.100.100.50 I get no response. When I use trace route I see this,

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 10.100.100.50

Tracing route to 10.100.100.50 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  kabelbox.local [192.168.0.1]
  2    17 ms    16 ms    16 ms  83-169-183-49-isp.superkabel.de [83.169.183.49]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

The packets are going to my internet router (connected via WiFi) which should not be happening.
If I turn off my laptop WiFi, then I can properly reach devices on the 10.100.** network.

How can I make sure that even with both these interfaces turned on, I can use the WiFi for my general internel usage and the cellular just to access 10.100** ips?

Comment: 10.100.100.8/29 does not include 10.100.100.50, so IP routing is sending those packets the the default gateway. Triple check the subnet mask(s) of your client(s).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a closer route to 10.100.100.50. The route for 10.100.100.8/29 has a usable range of    10.100.100.9 - 10.100.100.14.  If you want a route to 10.100.100.50 you should create it.

Comment: still then I should be able to ping my own ip (10.100.100.12), but even that is going to  the wrong interface

Comment: @SAS: What "devices" are on this network?

Comment: raspberry Pi(s), if just turn off my WiFi, then I am able to reach them so the problem is definitely in my routing. Also I noticed when I turn off wifi, windows auto adds this route                                                                                                                       
 Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface                         Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.100.100.13    10.100.100.12                     257                      which somehow fixes the issue (as long as wifi remains off)

Comment: @SAS: You may want to update the question with address(es) that are in the correct range.